# Can't install php5-apc from dotdeb source in Debian 6

Tags: php5, dotdeb

I can't install php5-apc:

```
~# apt-get install php5-apc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-apc : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.19-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.3.8-2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Have fresh Debian 6 and

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
```

in source.list.

P. S. I'm not very experienced—just trying to set up a server by [the tutorial](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/02/wordpress-nginx-part-1-preparing-vps-debian-linux/).

Comment: Are you sure you're up to date? apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I'm.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try downloading the debain package manually and try to install it. Go to [link](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php-apc) and select your system arch from the list given at the bottom to download.

Or you can also try editing source.list file and add the given below entry and try again.

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main
```